# Looking for a plugin which could publish my site rss to facebook timeline automaticlly

Tags: rss, facebook

I am looking for a plugin which could publish my site rss to facebook timeline automaticlly. The function like `rssgraffiti.com`.

For explain, if my wordpress site's rss (blog, post, bb press, buddypress stream, etc) updated, it will automaticlly publish to my facebook timeline. (Or if there is not a plugin like this, any other php script also good)

Thanks.

Comment: why not use rssgraffiti?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) seems to have that functionality. Look for the Social Publisher feature. It says: "*... allows you to publish to an author´s Facebook Timeline and Fan Page*"